# Create Several Feature Layers and add them to a MXD

Tags: python, arcpy, mxd

Every time I run this script now, I get an error on the line with the MakeFeatureLayer line. Sorry for all the questions! I'm really new to Python.

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\pathway to gdb'
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\pathway to mxd')
DF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,'*')[0]


for feature in fcs:
    inputlayer = 'C:\pathway to gdb' 
    outlayer = os.path.join(fcs, 'feature'+'.lyr')

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inputlayer,outlayer)

    layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(mxd)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DF,layer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")
```

Comment: can you run it from the "Python" window in ArcMap. I do that a lot with something like ...
execfile(r"C:\myfolder\myfile.py")

Comment: Does this question help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/21906/43

Comment: The question you posted Richard I had stumbled across before. However, how do you run this process in the foreground rather than the background?

Also, this needs to be run in IDLE.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to your [original question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/revisions/140490/1):**

There is no "CURRENT" MXD when running outside of ArcMap. Use `mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\full\path\to.mxd')` instead.

**Answer to your edited question:**

You can't create a Layer object from a MapDocument object (i.e. `layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(mxd)`). Do something like this instead:

```
for fc in fcs:
    layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(fc)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DF,layer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")
```