# ArcPy Not Able to Open Current Map From Stand Alone Code While Map Is Open

Tags: arcpy, runtimeerror

Running an Arcpy stand alone script on `PyScripter` I followed everything in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21906/arcpy-gives-error-object-createobject-cannot-open-map-document#answer-21907) to [ArcPy gives error Object: CreateObject cannot open map document?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21906)

As:

1. Start up the `Streets.mxd` in ArcMap
2. Run the `mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")` inside the ArcMap (without no error)

[image]
3- Add the same `mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")` to my code in `PyScripter` IDE as

```
import arcpy
####mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Temp\Street.mxd")
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Main", df)[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Data\NetMap.gdb\Streets\OneWay")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "BOTTOM")‍‍‍‍‍‍
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

but I am getting this runtime error message:

[image]

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\bhosseini\Documents\ArcPy\Trace With Graphics\module3.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 625,
>   in **init**
>       super(MapDocumentMethods, self).**init**(mxd)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects_base.py", line
>   47, in **init**
>       for arg in args)) **RuntimeError: Object: CreateObject cannot open map document**

Comment: The python script using `MapDocument("CURRENT")` must be run from the currently open MXD.  You can't use `CURRENT` from a stand-alone script because there's no MXD for it to use - it's running in a separate process so isn't aware of the one you already have open.

Comment: Please see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61158/using-current-map-document-in-python-script-tool

Comment: You said that you have "followed everything in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21906/arcpy-gives-error-object-createobject-cannot-open-map-document#answer-21907) to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21906" but that says that what you are trying to do cannot be done and what you are seeing is the expected software behaviour.